# Angular2, multiple views for a component?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Hi I have a webpage with multiple layouts that I want to switch to. Similar to codepen.io. What is the best way to do it in angular2?

Say I have 4 layouts. I can put `*ngIf="layout1"` and put first layout and then `*ngIf="layout2"` and put the second layout, and so forth. But is it the best way? Note that when changing the layout, both html and css changes.

Answer (score 1):

There is also `ngSwitch` which is convenient when there are more than one or two options. 
This way you have everything in one component. I think it's a good option if it is probable that switching between layouts is common and done often within one user session.

If this is mostly a one-off decision (for example based on the screen dimenions) one of the following options might be a better fit.

You can also use [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html). Each layout is packed in a component and you add the component that fits the current selection.
See also http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/loading-components-dynamically-in-angular-2.0

Another way is using the router to add a component depending on the Url or Url parameters.
See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html